# getParam("recordUI") on recordEditForm onload event returns 'undefined'

Tags: lightning-recordeditform

In a Tabs component, I am using a Record Detail component along with custom components in the Opportunity object. The goal of the custom pages/components is to display fields spread in different tabs and grouped logically.
The custom pages use a recordEditform component to retrieve, display and save data.
In one of my pages, I have to separate the data in 2 different sub-tabs. Sub-tab #1 is always displayed, sub-tab #2 is displayed conditionally. I manage the condition in an aura:if component.
The criteria of the aura:if is given in a field value in the current record. So I want to intercept the field value and set it in an aura:attribute which will be used by the aura:if. So I handle the 'onload' event to get the record data and set the attribute. and use var data = evt.getParam("recordUI"); for that.

Problem : evt.getParam("recordUI") returns 'undefined'.

What could be the reason for recordEditForm to return 'undefined' ? Is using the Record Detial component with custom components which use a recordEditForm an issue ? What could be a workaround ?

Thank you for your help.

**Component** :

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="auraIfCriteria" type="boolean" />

<lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="MyCustomPage"
                          objectApiName="Opportunity"
                          recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                          onload="{!c.hOnload}"
                          onsuccess="{!c.hOnSuccess}" 
/>
```

**Controller** :

```
({
    hOnload : function( component, evt, helper )    {
        var data = evt.getParam("recordUI");  // returns 'undefined'
        ...
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your capitalization is off. It should be event.getParam("recordUi"), lowercase i.

Comment: Yes. Just realized that. Thank you.